# Set mouse speed with profiles

Tags: ubuntu, mouse

I have two mice, one at home with resolution 800dpi and one at work with resolution 1000dpi.
The two mice behave differently. When I come to work, I need to set the pointer speed to max. When I work from home, I need to turn the speed down a bit.

I would like to have profiles for the two mice. Ideally, these would be applied automatically, depending on what mouse is connected.
How would I do that?

Running Ubuntu 15.10.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can detect which mouse is connected in X11 using `xinput`. Eg

```
$ xinput --list
...
Logitech USB Optical Mouse               id=11   [slave  pointer  (2)]
```

Note the value in `id=`, 11 in this example, which is the device's id.
You can use this id to set the ratio for mouse movement:

```
xinput --set-ptr-feedback $id threshold numerator denominator
```

or simply

```
xset m numerator/denominator threshold
```

To auto-detect a change in mouse is a little more difficult. The simplest is to run `udevadm monitor` and look for the udev events generated when a mouse in plugged in.